what are the 3 input pins/terminals on a hv microwave transformer
this is from a samsung ME19R7041FW
it makes buzzing noise when plugged in and I have 120 V between the black wire and either of the two above. are the blue and white the power supply and if yes what is the black and why do I have voltage on it?
the white and blue lead to two relays soldered to the main board and the blue harness one is stuck in closed.
transformer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19LXDUR04kDsuS0RnkXnkvRm_Ftmb9FAv/view?usp=sharing
main with relays:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19oldcbx_o3ZB6Nf3_BhSkNn5U3djVxkA/view?usp=sharing
